# What has been changed in Ubuntu's own GTK 2 & 3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

I am considering how to write an global menu applet for cinnamon. I searched the internet and found a project named [Unity-for-Arch](https://github.com/chenxiaolong/Unity-for-Arch). The project provides the possibility to port Unity to Archlinux. But the project uses different version of gtk2 and gtk3,called gtk2-ubuntu and gtk3-ubuntu. The project is the only project I found which can realize global menu in non Ubuntu Linux distribution nowadays. So I think that maybe I need to inspect what changes have been aplied to gtk2 and gtk3 in Ubuntu. 
Do the changes to gtk2 and gtk3 in Ubuntu contribute to Unity's global menu?